# Привязка сессии к динамическому ip

Tags: ip, сессия, php

Доброе утро
Есть варианты привязки сессии к динамическому ip?

Comment: К динамическому айпи нельзя привязать ничего, потому что он сменится через пятнадцать минут (разве что на этот промежуток времени). Привязка к пользователю  с динамическим айпи выполняется автоматически, потому что она реализована на уровне куки, где айпи не играет никакой роли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Динамический IP ничем не отличается от статического (кроме того что через некоторое время он изменится). Веб-приложение не может определить является-ли некоторый IP динамическим (строго говоря термин «динамический IP» не имеет строгого технического определения).

Сессия может либо привязываться к IP либо нет. С точки зрения клиента если сессия пользователя привязана к IP то при смене IP сессия оборвётся. Пока IP не изменится — сессия будет жить (если забыть о том что у сессии может быть задан период протухания).

Если у посетителя IP меняется раз в n минут то сессия у него будет рваться раз в n минут. Если IP не меняется никогда («никогда» это очень громкое слово) то сессия не порвётся.

Если вы хотите что-бы у посетителей с динамическими IP не рвались сессии — не привязывайте сессии к IP. Но это менее безопасно.

P.S. пришёл на ум промежуточный вариант между привязкой и не привязкой — привязывать сессию к подсети. Либо тупо отрезать от IP последние 1 - 2 октета, либо смотреть по whois какую подсеть использует провайдер посетителя. Правда это более геморройно, и не факт что от этого будет хоть какой-то толк.

Comment: мой isp меняет ip в куче сетей /8 :) нет от этого толку. да и про менее-более... тут же как, если у вас mitm и не ssl, то он вас проксит... делаем выводы.

Comment: Ну да, поможет разве-что от покражи кук каким-то вредоносным кодом на компе.

Что до подсетей то обычно пулы IPов оператора более кучные и сведены в одну автономную систему (AS), так-что более менее угадать можно. но вообще идея изначально на правах бреда.

Comment: да я говорю же, сегодня 241..0/8 а завтра 92..0/8 такие дела :) тогда уж к geoip привязывать :)

Comment: Я говорю про «обычно»,а не «всегда».